# What could cause Safari to reject secure SSL websocket ws://?

Tags: ssl, safari, websocket

Received a strange error when using secure websockets in Safari with Webbit server.

`Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: wss://domain.com:5679/ != ws://domain.com:5679/`

I have no idea why this would happen or how to get around it. Is this a bug on the Webbit server or a client-side bug?

Comment: Appears to be a bug, I've submitted a bug report to Webbit. I believe this has been experienced by other websocket libraries, too https://github.com/webbit/webbit/issues/82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed it was a bug. Glad to report that this was fixed in both the Hixie 75 and 76 protocol specs in Webbit via this pull request https://github.com/webbit/webbit/pull/84

If you are using any other websocket libraries other than Webbit, I suggest tracking down the source and looking for where the protocol is determined when responding to a secure websocket request.